# whether given two words are synonyms or not

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this task, your job will be to write a program that can decide whether two words are synonyms or not. You will get a synonym dictionary describing pairs of synonymous words. Afterwards, you will answer several queries asking whether given two words are synonyms or not. Both dictionary of synonym pairs and queries for your program will be included in the input file.

Use the following rules to decide:

1. If the pair of words is declared synonymous in the input, then they are synonyms.
2. Being synonyms doesn't depend on order, e.g. if big is a synonym for large then large is a synonym for big.
3. We can derive the synonymous relationship indirectly: if big is a synonym for large and large is a synonym for huge then big is a synonym for huge.
4. If two words differ only by case, they are synonyms, e.g. same is a synonym for both SAmE, SAME and also same (itself).
5. If none of the above rules can be used to decide whether two words are synonyms, then they are not.

**Input :**

Input starts with a number of test cases T (0 < T < 100). Each test case begins with a line containing a single number N (0 N s 100) — the length of a synonym dictionary. On each of the following N lines, there is exactly one pair of synonyms separated by a single space. Next line contains a single number Q (0 Q 100) — number of queries. Each of the following lines contains a pair of query words separated by a single space.
Each word consists only of English alphabet letters ( [a- zA-Z] ) and is at most 20 characters long.

**Output :**

For each pair of query words output either string **synonyms** or **different** .

**Sample input**

```
2
4 
big large 
large huge 
small little 
apple banana
6 
same same 
big huge 
huge big 
apple peach 
big tall 
peach PEACH
5 
wood FORest 
meadoW PrAirIe 
WOOD Lumber 
lumber forest 
lumber forest
2 
wood LUMBER 
mEADOw fire
```

**Sample output**

```
synonyms 
synonyms 
synonyms 
different 
different 
synonyms 
synonyms 
different
```

**Explanation of the sample problem**

In the first test-case there are 6 queries:

1. Words are the same.
2. Words are derived synonyms.
3. Symmetric to 2nd query.
4. No rule can be used to derive the synonym pair.
5. No rule can be used to derive the synonym pair, even though they are synonyms in English.
6. Words differ only in case.
   2 nd test case:
7. Defined as synonyms by 3rd rule. The case does not matter.

Comment: What criteria determines whether two words are synonyms?

Comment: i am looking for a implementation idea for the same

Comment: You can use any free API to get the synonyms of words. Here's one that you can use - https://www.wordsapi.com/ . Get the synonyms of the first word and check if the second word is in it.

Comment: can you please share the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Harvard University and Google in 2010  estimated a total of 1,022,000 words and that the number would grow by several thousand each year.

So, logically your code should know about all of them in order to work properly. Such database of words, their linkage and access methods are provided by external APIs. Your applicatin should search for synonyms using one of these APIs.

Here are some of them-

https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-nodejs-dictionary-api-libraries

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in function in Node to test whether some word is a synonym or not. But (fortunately) there are some libraries to do that.

Here's an example:
First, install the `synonyms` package from NPM:

```
npm i synonyms
```

Then, in your JS file:

```js
const synonyms = require("synonyms"); // Import the "synonyms" library
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("path/to/file", "utf-8", (err, file) => {
  // Read the file
  const lines = file.split("\n"); // Each line is split into an array
  let result = lines.map(i => {
    return i.split(" ");
  }); // "result" holds an array of arrays. Index 0 is word 1 and index 1 is word 2

  result.forEach(item => {
    // Loop through our words
    const s = synonyms(item[0].toLowerCase()); // Call the function
    let allSynonyms = [];
    for (let q in s) {
      s[q].forEach(i => {
        if(typeof i === "object")
          i.forEach(allSynonyms.push);
        else allSynonyms.push(i);
      });
    }
    if (allSynonyms.includes(item[1].toLowerCase())) {
      console.log(`Yes, "${item[0]}" is a synonym with "${item[1]}"!`); // Yes
    } else {
      // Nope!
      console.log(`Nope, "${item[0]}" is not a synonym with "${item[1]}".`);
    }
  });
});
```

Just an example :) You can check the result [here](https://glitch.com/edit/console.html?synonym). Just run `npm start`.

Comment: I do not quite understand the question though, however, I managed to solve it in a way that I think would be of help to you.

First, let me explain what I think they are asking, the First line defines the **Test Case** the next is the number of lines of the Dictionary item, next is the words you're to query check the synonyms following the given rule set, and next another dictionary followed by the query and so on...

Based on that :::

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble pasting the block of code here. I added a gist file to the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/acushlakoncept/189e0c3acb19aa65c3a3ab411afb4feb)

Comment: @Acushla what does your other files look like, e.g. `example.in`?

Comment: ```
2
4
big large
large huge
small little
apple banana
6
same same
big huge
huge big
apple peach
big tall
peach PEACH
5
wood FORest
meadoW PrAirIe
WOOD Lumber
lumber forest
lumber forest
2
wood LUMBER
mEADOw fire
```